# How to periodically check latest stable version of chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I’ve tried looking at Google’s git repo, and I just see so many tags with different version numbers. Any suggestions of how to periodically check for a new chrome version that gets released with js code? I’m not sure what kind of data scraping I need to do, if any.

Comment: Can you give a bit more info about where this is going to be run (e.g. client-side, server-side, as a script, etc) as the answer would depend on that

Comment: And have you tried anything so far? If so, include what you've tried in your question, with code snippets

Comment: I haven’t gotten the chance too yet, since it’s something I’m considering making into a simple web server/app for my IT dept. We have the problem of checking for new chrome releases greater than 100. We have a regex to help us with this when checking KACE for a list of devices with chrome installed, but we would constantly have to change it for every new chrome release. @Lissy93

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current Chrome versions from this endpoint:

```
https://versionhistory.googleapis.com/v1/chrome/platforms/win/channels/stable/versions
```

For more information on that, see the [Chrome Version Guide Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/versionhistory/guide/).

And to check this periodically would depend on how/ where you are running this code, if you provide more info to your question I can give you a sample code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

you might scrape the information from this site: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-version/chrome

Comment: What about the [Chrome Version API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/versionhistory/guide/)? E.g, this endpoint: `https://versionhistory.googleapis.com/v1/chrome/platforms/win/channels/stable/versions
`

Comment: What about API showing only the latest version number rather than showing all version info?